# Factory bot error "private method `new' called for User:Class (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I m new to factory bot, I try to create a sample data using factory bot but I got this error

How to resolve this error?

features/support/factories.rb:

```
require 'factory_bot'


FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email "xxx123@xyz.co"
    password "asdf123"
    password_confirmation "asdf123"
  end
end
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Show your `User` class.

Comment: Your code should work fine under normal circumstances. You must have done something weird in the `User` class (e.g. redefine `User.new` as a private method???!!!). Please show us the `User` class; i.e. provide a [mcve] of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require 'factory_bot'

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email "xxx123@xyz.co"
    password "asdf123"
    password_confirmation "asdf123"
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    user
  end
end
```

as described in [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) documentation

> ## Associations
>
> It's possible to set up associations within factories. If the factory name is the same as the association name, the factory name can be left out.

```
factory :post do
  # ...
  author
end
```

> You can also specify a different factory or override attributes:

```
factory :post do
  # ...
  association :author, factory: :user, last_name: "Writely"
end
```

Comment: Thank to inform this guy and one more doubt how to call the user and when

Comment: so in your `rails console test` you can do `post = FactoryBot.create(:post)`, it will return the user when you do `post.user` it returns `=> User #.....` etc..